# Creating dynamic xml in java

Tags: java

I'm new to creating xmls.I'm able to create small xml but,I need to create dynamic xml based on the information send from the user ,required xml format is

can any one help me to create the above xml.

Comment: Please post the XML Format you are after.

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing required is XML format, you can choose [NanoXML](http://devkix.com/nanoxml.php), which is very light and has simple API.

If you want to change Java objects into XML, your best choice may be [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), in which object-to-XML is single line instruction.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to try [StAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX). It's part of standard java api, and it's quite simple to use.

Here is [great tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaXML/article.html) to start with StAX

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create String representations of XML only? Then by far the most pragmatic way to do so is by simply using Strings. For example:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String asXML() {
        return String.format("<person><name>%s</name></person>", name);
    }
}
```

You can compose graphs of objects in this way, call `asXML` on the top level object and get an entire document.